# How to handle the duplicate block of content?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, googlebot, search-results

Please refer: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en

Googlebot don't like duplicate content and also duplicate block of content repeatedly copy and pasted in many pages. I think, I have genuine case, Where I display my package details. I have around 6 packages (which is not in a image format), in a HTML format with all the packages information.

To have a call for action or to lead to a successful sales, I display all these packages in all the pages so that, I can take my users to the payment page quickly. But Google considers this as a duplicate block of content.

Example: (Randomly selected two images just to present it here) (but in my case, these blocks presented as a HTML in all the pages)

[image]
[image]

When Google sees these same block of content along with other contents in multiple pages, it is considering as a duplicate.

How can I handle this ?

One way, I can think of is, How about keeping the packages details in a image format ?

Comment: Duplicate blocks of content is fine. Do what is right for your users and your site.

Comment: For the more generic tour packages listing, you may want to consider randomizing the output, so the bullets aren't always in the same order.  In addition to that, you can add some javascript to randomize the headings of each callout.  For instance, Book your Kashmir Tour Package today! or Kashmir Tour Package Special.

Otherwise, like @closetnoc stated- keep the calls-to-action if they serve a function to your users and for your site.